# convert dictionary to list model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
var entity = await _abcRepository.get(Id);
var X = entity.GroupBy(c => c.number).Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1).Take(10).ToList();
```

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

in images you see [0] and inside of it one more [0].
How can I get that model value.

`X[0][0]` is not working.

`X.Value` is not working.

I need to convert that dictionary to model.

Comment: Please don't post images unless your question is UI related.

Comment: sorry about that. I didn't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Select` to normalize aggregation as per your wish.

```
var X = entity.GroupBy(c => c.number).Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1)
    .Select(group => new { GroupKey = group.Key, Items = group.ToList() })
    .Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: I added a foreach below that.   foreach (var item in X)
            {
                listModel.Add(item.Items[0]);
            }
that solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var entity = await _abcRepository.get(Id);
var results = entity.GroupBy(c => c.number)
                    .Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1)
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.First());
```

Essentially, the lambda you pass in `Where` method certifies that the groups are created contains only one item. That being said, you can use the `First` on each group to fetch that one element.